# Pandas Create Date Column for Fiscar QTR/Year

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to create a new date column in my dataframe. The date column is formatted as such, ex. '2019-02-04'

```
def fiscal_date(row):
    if row['Date'] >= '2018-02-01' and row['Date'] < '2018-05-01':
        return 'FY19 Q1'
    if row['Date'] >= '2018-05-01' and row['Date'] < '2018-08-01':
        return 'FY19 Q2'
    if row['Date'] >= '2018-08-01' and row['Date'] < '2018-11-01':
        return 'FY19 Q3'
```

when I try to apply the function, data['Fiscal'] = data.apply(fiscal_date, axis=1)
Getting this Error:
TypeError: ("'>=' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'str'", 'occurred at index 0')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the error is coming from this part: `if row['Date'] >= '2018-02-01'` , where you trying to compare `row['Date']` which is Timestamp with `'2018-02-01'` which is string. The `'2018-02-01'` should be converted to datetime object:

```
import datetime

datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-02-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see in your second comparison you never specify row.

Try writing `row['Date'] < '2018-05-01'` instead of just `['Date'] < '2018-05-01'`.

Like this:

```
if row['Date'] >= '2018-02-01' and row['Date'] < '2018-05-01':
```

Comment: sorry that was a typo